# Error in checking whether a string is palindrome

Tags: c, recursion, stack

I'm trying to make a C program that checks whether a sequence of characters is palindrome or not.
I must use a stack and a recursive function.

The first number given as input is the length of the string. The program works correctly with even lengths, but doesn't recognize palindromeness of odd strings. I have been trying to find the mistake for at least an hour but no luck.

This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct c {
    char cha;
    struct c *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct c Character;

void push(Character **headPtr, char c) {
    Character *newC = malloc(sizeof(Character));

    if(newC == NULL) {
        puts("Insufficient memory.");
    }
    newC->cha = c;
    newC->nextPtr = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = newC;
}

char pop(Character **headPtr) {
    if(*headPtr != NULL) {
        Character *tempPtr = *headPtr;
        char c = (*headPtr)->cha;
        *headPtr = (*headPtr)->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);
        return c;
    }
}

void isPalindrome(int stringLength, int charNum) {
    static Character *headPtr = NULL;

    if(stringLength == 1) {
        puts("Palindrome");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(charNum < (stringLength/2)) {
        char c = getchar();
        push(&headPtr, c);
        return isPalindrome(stringLength, charNum+1);
    }
    if(stringLength % 2) {
        getchar();
    }

    char d = getchar();
    char e = pop(&headPtr);
    if(d != e) {
        puts("Not palindrome");
        exit(0);
    }
    return;
}

int main() {
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    isPalindrome(n, 0);

    puts("Palindrome.");
    return 0;
}
```

You can try it yourself by just inputting an odd number, then enter, than a sequence of characters. The program will not recognize if it's palindrome and always say it's not or even do weirder stuff like not outputting anything at all and waiting for more input.

I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: `if(*headPtr != NULL)` in `pop`, you do not return anything. It indicates you must turn warnings of your compiler on as it would have told you this. That may reveal more problems.

Comment: `if(newC == NULL)` in `push`, you must `return;`

Comment: Why do you represent the sequence of characters as a linked list? This is insane.

Comment: @Lxer I am required to do so. It's an exercise

Comment: That would be a one-liner if the character sequence were represented as a string: `bool pal (const char *s, size_t n){ return n < 2 ? true : s[0] == s[n - 1] && pal(s + 1, n - 2);}`. Using it as `bool is_palindrome = pal(s, strlen(s));`

Comment: I know but I must use a stack.

Comment: don't use `while(something);` as it will confound people, use better `while(something) {}` or even better `while(something) continue;` so everybody knows that your empty loop was intentional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution by myself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isPal = 1;

struct c {
    char cha;
    struct c *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct c Character;

void push(Character **headPtr, char c) {
    Character *newC = malloc(sizeof(Character));

    if(newC == NULL) {
        puts("Insufficient memory.");
        return;
    }
    newC->cha = c;
    newC->nextPtr = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = newC;
}

char pop(Character **headPtr) {
    if(*headPtr != NULL) {
        Character *tempPtr = *headPtr;
        char c = (*headPtr)->cha;
        *headPtr = (*headPtr)->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);
        return c;
    }
}

void isPalindrome(int stringLength, int charNum) {
    if(!isPal) return;

    static Character *stack = NULL;

    if(charNum < (stringLength/2)) {
        char c = getchar();
        push(&stack, c);
        isPalindrome(stringLength, charNum+1);
    } else if(stringLength % 2) {
        getchar();
    }

    char d = getchar();
    char e = pop(&stack);
    if(d != '\n' && d != e) isPal = 0;
}

int main() {
    int n;

    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0) {
        puts("Incorrect input.");
        return 0;
    }
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    if(n>1) isPalindrome(n, 0);

    if(isPal) puts("Palindrome.");
    else puts("Not palindrome.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer should explain what your problem was and how you solved it.  Just posting a bunch of code is not likely to be helpful to any future readers who might have a similar problem.